# React bundle.js resets whole DOM created by server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to optimize my universal react application. 
It seems bundle.js which is read after server side rendering resets the whole DOM.

My understanding was that React client side javascript does not reset the whole DOM but calculates diff and attaches additional DOM and event on existing DOM.

My bundle.js is 1.3 MB which is definitely the cause of slow rendering but I was not expected re-render whole DOM.

My question is
Is it expected behavior for universal rendering? and how to not reset all DOM?

[image]

**server/index.js**

```
const store = configureStore()

//****************
// App Setting
//**************** 

debug("Setting Application...")

const app = new Express()

app.use('/assets', Express.static('./assets'))
app.use('/build', Express.static('./build'))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

  const history = createHistory(req.originalUrl)

  match({history, routes: createRoutes(store), location: req.originalUrl}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps)=>{


    const routes = createRoutes(store)
    const components = (
      <Provider store={store} key="provider">
        <RouterContext {...renderProps} /> 
      </Provider>
    )

    // React Dom Server Side Rendering
    const app = ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(<HTML components={components} store={store}/>)

    // Response 200
    res.status(200)

    // Send response HTML
    res.send(`<!doctype html>\n ${app}`)

  })
})

app.listen(7777, () => debug('Server running on localhost:7777'))
```

**client/index.js**

```
let store

if (window.__REDUX_STORE__) {
  store = configureStore(window.__REDUX_STORE__)
} else {
  store = configureStore()
}

store.dispatch(fetchCurrentUserRequest())

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#content')
);
```

**HTML.jsx**

```
class HTML extends Component {

  render(){
    const { components, store } = this.props;
    const content = components ? ReactDOM.renderToString(components): '';

    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/style.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <style>
            * {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
            }
          </style>
          <div id="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}}/>
          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `window.__REDUX_STORE__=${serialize(store.getState())};`}} charSet="UTF-8"/>
          <script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDnd7VpVekR7d09azP_RQ5Bb_bQHKMkSVo&libraries=places"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}

export default HTML
```

Comment: Are there warnings in the console? It will only re-create the DOM if the server rendered something and the client tried to render something different. The whole component tree is executed client side to assign click handlers, but the DOM shouldn't be mutated unless it's different

Comment: There is warinings on server side.
`2017-01-04 19:42 : Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop 'router' was not specified in 'RouterContext'.
    in RouterContext`. Same error on props location, routes, params, components as well